# Setting Inheritance and Propagation flags with set-acl and powershell

Tags: powershell, permissions, file-permissions

I am trying to mimic the action of right-clicking on a folder, setting "modify" on a folder, and having the permissions apply to the specific folder and subfolders and files.

I'm mostly there using Powershell, however the inheritance is only being set as "subfolders and files" instead of the whole "this folder, subfolders and files".

Is there some unlisted flag for System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags that will set this properly?

Here's what I'm working with so far.

```
$Folders = Get-childItem c:\TEMP\
$InheritanceFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::ContainerInherit -bor [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::ObjectInherit
$PropagationFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::InheritOnly
$objType = [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow 

foreach ($TempFolder in $Folders)
{
echo "Loop Iteration"
$Folder = $TempFolder.FullName

$acl = Get-Acl $Folder
$permission = "domain\user","Modify", $InheritanceFlag, $PropagationFlag, $objType
$accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $permission

$acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule)
Set-Acl $Folder $acl
}
```

Comment: I made a chart of the mapping between the file permissions dialogs and resulting permissions: http://bit.ly/inheritMatrix

Comment: Please add the modification from the code below you did in order to make this work

Comment: @JosephKingry, the link is asking to Sign in to continue to Sheets?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I think your answer can be found on [this page](http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2007/06/18/directory-security-and-access-rules.aspx).  From the page:

> This Folder, Subfolders and Files:
>
> ```
> InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit 
> PropagationFlags.None
> ```

Comment: Could you please add the code? Linking to a page and quoting IMO is not a proper answer.

Answer (score 109):

Here's a table to help find the required flags for different permission combinations.

```
    ╔═════════════╦═════════════╦═══════════════════════════════╦════════════════════════╦══════════════════╦═══════════════════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╗
    ║             ║ folder only ║ folder, sub-folders and files ║ folder and sub-folders ║ folder and files ║ sub-folders and files ║ sub-folders ║    files    ║
    ╠═════════════╬═════════════╬═══════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬══════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╣
    ║ Propagation ║ none        ║ none                          ║ none                   ║ none             ║ InheritOnly           ║ InheritOnly ║ InheritOnly ║
    ║ Inheritance ║ none        ║ Container|Object              ║ Container              ║ Object           ║ Container|Object      ║ Container   ║ Object      ║
    ╚═════════════╩═════════════╩═══════════════════════════════╩════════════════════════╩══════════════════╩═══════════════════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╝
```

So, [as David said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3283010/1574221), you'll want

```
InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags.None
```

Comment: +1 for the table. Would give an extra +1 just for the box-drawing characters, if only I could :)

Comment: Why is Folder/files Different from subfolder/files in inheritance?

Answer (score 17):

Here's some succinct Powershell code to apply new permissions to a folder by modifying it's existing ACL (Access Control List).

```
# Get the ACL for an existing folder
$existingAcl = Get-Acl -Path 'C:\DemoFolder'

# Set the permissions that you want to apply to the folder
$permissions = $env:username, 'Read,Modify', 'ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit', 'None', 'Allow'

# Create a new FileSystemAccessRule object
$rule = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule -ArgumentList $permissions

# Modify the existing ACL to include the new rule
$existingAcl.SetAccessRule($rule)

# Apply the modified access rule to the folder
$existingAcl | Set-Acl -Path 'C:\DemoFolder'
```

Each of the values in the `$permissions` variable list pertain to the parameters of [this constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfe70whw(v=vs.110).aspx) for the [FileSystemAccessRule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Courtesy of [this page](http://ss64.com/ps/set-acl.html).

Comment: The key for powershell is to pass the flags as parameters to the constructor for FileSystemAccessRule (i.e. New-Object) as only this answer shows.

Comment: @bchurchill wait, there's a difference between inheritance/propagation at the ACL and ACE level, though. So setting it in the ctor of FileSystemAccessRule affects the ACE, but won't affect the ACL flags. Or what am I missing?

Comment: I think you're right, the answer here just adds a new entry with those flags set, which may work in some cases but not others.

Answer (score 12):

Just because you're in PowerShell don't forgot about good ol' exes.  Sometimes they can provide the easiest solution e.g.:

```
icacls.exe $folder /grant 'domain\user:(OI)(CI)(M)'
```

Comment: Yeah, I almost solved the problems with a DOS batch file and icacls or setacl, but trying to learn powershell.. best way to learn is by solving a problem with it, etc.

Comment: I understand.  OTOH I've been using PowerShell for > 5 years now and I don't hesitate to drop back to an EXE if it is significantly easier than the PowerShell equivalent.  IOW there's plenty to learn in PowerShell - some more worthwhile than others. :-)

Comment: The annoying part about icacls appears to be the fact that it uses an older version/dialect of SDDL.

Answer (score 9):

Here's [the MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229747(v=vs.100).aspx) describing the flags and what is the result of their various combinations.

```
Flag combinations => Propagation results
=========================================
No Flags => Target folder.
ObjectInherit => Target folder, child object (file), grandchild object (file).
ObjectInherit and NoPropagateInherit => Target folder, child object (file).
ObjectInherit and InheritOnly => Child object (file), grandchild object (file).
ObjectInherit, InheritOnly, and NoPropagateInherit => Child object (file).
ContainerInherit => Target folder, child folder, grandchild folder.
ContainerInherit, and NoPropagateInherit => Target folder, child folder.
ContainerInherit, and InheritOnly => Child folder, grandchild folder.
ContainerInherit, InheritOnly, and NoPropagateInherit => Child folder.
ContainerInherit, and ObjectInherit => Target folder, child folder, child object (file), grandchild folder, grandchild object (file).
ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit, and NoPropagateInherit => Target folder, child folder, child object (file).
ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit, and InheritOnly => Child folder, child object (file), grandchild folder, grandchild object (file).
ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit, NoPropagateInherit, InheritOnly => Child folder, child object (file).
```

To have it apply the permissions to the directory, as well as all child directories and files recursively, you'll want to use these flags:

```
InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit 
PropagationFlags.None
```

So the specific code change you need to make for your example is:

```
$PropagationFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::None
```