# Powershell Setting Inheritance

Tags: powershell, file, directory, permissions

I was following another question regarding a similar problem found here: [Setting Inheritance and Propagation flags with set-acl and powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282656/setting-inheritance-and-propagation-flags-with-set-acl-and-powershell)

[Powershell Check Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UmDt.png)

This partially worked for me, except the "IsInherited" output from powershell says false.

```
# Get the ACL for an existing folder
$existingAcl = Get-Acl -Path \\fp01\Users\$newuser

# Set the permissions that you want to apply to the folder
$permissions = $newuser, 'FullControl', 'ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit', 'None', 'Allow'

# Create a new FileSystemAccessRule object
$rule = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule -ArgumentList $permissions

# Modify the existing ACL to include the new rule
$existingAcl.SetAccessRule($rule)

# Apply the modified access rule to the folder
$existingAcl | Set-Acl -Path \\fp01\Users\$newuser

# Check permissions
(Get-ACL -Path "\\fp01\Users\$newuser").Access | Format-Table IdentityReference,FileSystemRights,AccessControlType,IsInherited,InheritanceFlags -AutoSize
```

This is a snippit from a much longer script, so the $newuser parameter is already set. I just cant figure out why inheritance is set to false ever though it is object and container inherited.

Thank you all in advanced!